# Convert a non-convex QCQP into a convex counterpart

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

**Problem**

We consider a possibly non-convex QCQP, with nonnegative variable $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_0(x) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & f_i(x) \leq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m\\
& & & x \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

where $f_i(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TP_ix+q_i^Tx+r_i$, with $P_i\in \mathbb{S}^n$, $q_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $r_i \in \mathbb{R}$, for $i=0,\cdots,m$. We **do not** assume that $P_i\geq0$, so this need not to be a convex problem.

Suppose that $q_i\leq 0$ and $P_i$ have non-positive off-diagonal entries. Explain how to reformulate this problem as a convex problem.

**What I Have Done**

Since both objective function and constraints are possibly non-convex, I consider their common structure, that is $f_i(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TP_ix+q_i^Tx+r_i, \ i=0,1,2,\cdots,m$. In this structure, $q_i^Tx+r_i$ part is affine, so it does not cause problem. Then I only consider $x^TP_ix$.

- The first thing that arises in my mind is to decompose $P_i$ into certain form and make $x^TP_ix$ become something like $y^TQy$ where $Q \geq 0$. However, I did not find anything useful (actually it seems that I **should not** or any non-convex quadratic programming could be solved in this way).
- Even though the previous random thought does not seem to work, I still think certain transformation is necessary, and perhaps some non-linear transformation $y_i=\phi (x_i)$. But coming up with this may need some "magic" and up to now have found anything that helps.

Could someone help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you not missing any assumption? For example with your setup it is easy to create a constraint $x^2\leq y^2+z^2$ and then I think it becomes a problem.

Comment: What makes you think this would be possible (it is not, as for instance binary optimization is a special case of your setup)

Comment: scratch my binary example, I just saw the $q_i\leq 0$ condition (although still impossible, as indicated by the example above)

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I do not quite understand your point. What does $y$ and $z$ stand for? Could you provide more information?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Actually this is a homework problem and I have been working on it for almost a week, so hopefully there is certain way to reformulate this (seemingly impossible) problem.

Comment: @Mr.Robot I mean $x_1^2\leq x_2^2+x_3^2$.

Answer (score 3):

I finally came up with a solution, which seems to be a valid reformulation.

Expand $f_i(x) \ (i=0,1,\cdots,m)$ into the form (form clarity, I drop the subscript in $f_i(x), P_i$ and $q_i$.
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i^{n}P_{ii}x_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}P_{ij}x_i x_j+ \sum_i^n q_i x_i + r$$

Notice that $x \geq 0$, apply the change of variable $y_i=x_i^2$, we have

$$f(y)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i^{n}P_{ii}y_i+\sum_{i\neq j}P_{ij}\sqrt{y_i y_j}+ \sum_i^n q_i\sqrt{y_i} + r$$

The first term $\sum_i^{n}P_{ii}y_i$ is affine in $y_i$. What is more, since the off-diagonal entries of $P$ are non-positive and this makes the second term convex. Similarly, the last term $\sum_i^n q_i\sqrt{y_i} + r$ is also convex. Then $f(y)$ is convex.

The "hint" directly from the problem is provided by $x\geq 0$, what indicates the possibility of taking the square root.

Comment: Aha, nice. Yes it appears correct